# Ошибка с Rigidbody2D.AddForce

Tags: unity3d

Делаю игру "Ping Pong". Написал скрипт, который должен толкнуть мяч в начале, при запуске ошибка.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object Ball.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Ball.cs:13)

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D Rigidbody2D;
    void Start()
    {
        float randomNum = Random.Range(0,2);
        if (randomNum <= 0.5) {
            Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(80, 10));
        }
        else {
            Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(-80, -10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Где/когда вы создаете экземпляр/инициализируете `Rigidbody2D`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке сказано - "Отсутствует ссылка на `Component Rigidbody2D`".
В скрипте достаточно прописать:

```
private void Awake()
{
    Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

P.S Документация на [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html)