# Почему InitializeComponent(); выдает System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

В своем проекте я использую :

1. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
2. CommunityToolkit.Mvvm;

При старте приложения в App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var authViewModel = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuthViewModel>();
        var authWindow = new AuthWindow { DataContext = authViewModel };
        authWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ExaminationWindow>();
        services.AddTransient<ExaminationViewModel>();
        services.AddTransient<TimetableViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<TimetableUserControl>();
        services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
        services.AddTransient<AuthViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        services.AddSingleton<AuthWindow>();
    }
}
```

Конструктор AuthViewModel:

```
public AuthViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
}
```

AuthWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public AuthWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

И все запускается нормально, так же у меня UserControl в котором представлено расписание, который находится в MainWindow, MainWindow через сервис открывается после успешного входа в AuthWindow.
NavigationService:

```
public NavigationService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
public void ShowMainWindow()
{
    var timetableViewModel = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TimetableViewModel>();
    var timetableUserControl = new TimetableUserControl { DataContext = timetableViewModel };
    var mainWindow = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.table = timetableUserControl;
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Конструктор TimetableViewModel:

```
public TimetableViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
    FullSchedule = new ObservableCollection<Timetable>(Timetable.SetTimetable(GlobalState.Instance.CurrentUser.Id));
    Test = "12345";
}
```

TimetableUserControl:

```
public TimetableUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Но этот код выдает ошибку после входа и выдает что InitializeComponent(); System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Пытался решить различными способами, дошел до такого вида программы, как я думал это решит проблему, но нет.
В чем заключается проблема и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Не согласен, что мой вопрос дубликат. В своем вопросе я спрашиваю про ошибку в контексте, которого не было в том вопросе, который Вы указали, следовательно ответа на мой вопрос там нет

Comment: Ошибку целиком прикладывайте, и XAML. Метод `InitializeComponent` отвечает за инициализацию XAML, его чтение, создание всех контролов. Если у вас ошибка именно на нем, то значит проблема в XAML.