# Делаю 2D игру на Юнити.Cобирался сделать мини квесты , создал скрипт quests, добавил его nps ,и вылезла ошибка

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Quests.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other)

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int questNumber;
    public int[] items;
    public GameObject[] clouds;
    public GameObject barrier;
    public GameObject key;

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag != "Player" && other.gameObject.GetComponent<Pickup>().id == items[questNumber])
        {
            questNumber++;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            CheckQuest();
        }
    }
    public void CheckQuest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++) 
        {
            if(i == questNumber)
            {
                clouds[i].SetActive(true);
                clouds[i].GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("isTriggered");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                clouds[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
        if(questNumber == 3)
        {
            barrier.SetActive(false);

        }
        if(questNumber == 4) 
        {
            key.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: ПРедположу что в инспекторе вы забыли добавить нужные объекты